# Masonry images overlapping

Tags: themes, blogs, tumblr, overlap

so I'm working on my Tumblr Theme right now. I'm using Masonry to have all my posts in a 5-column grid and the infinite scroll script to load new images into the grid when I'm scrolling down. Unfortunately, most of the time as I scroll down images are overlapping. I figured out that the problem may be Masonry triggering before the images are loaded, but right now I have no idea how to fix this. I'm already using (window).load instead of (document).ready but the pictures keep overlapping nonetheless. Here's the full code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/imovwvl/dJWl20ley/jqueryformasonry.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/imovwvl/rSGl20lfv/masonry.js">
</script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/df28qmy/SHUlh3i7s/jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/thpaaos/lLwkowcqm/jquery.masonry.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(window).load(function () {
$('.posts').masonry(),
$('.masonryWrap').infinitescroll({
navSelector : "div#navigation",
// selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
nextSelector : "div#navigation a#nextPage",
// selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : ".entry",
// selector for all items you'll retrieve
bufferPx : 10000,
extraScrollPx: 11000,
loadingImg : "",
loadingText : "<em></em>",
},
// call masonry as a callback.
function() { $('.posts').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) }); }
);
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(window).load(function(){$("p").remove(":contains('Source:')");});</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to get it working? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Masonry is placing the items absolutely before your images have loaded and take more space. 
Utilize Jquery imagesLoaded to overcome this.  You may want to initially hide your elements and then show them after they have finished loading. Try something like this:

```
//Wire masonry onto the photolist with whatever defaults you need
$photolist.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $photolist.masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector: '.photo',
        columnWidth: 226,
        isFitWidth: true,
        gutterWidth: 12
    });
});
```